# Control the window size in elasticsearch highlight results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to extract the results of the `span_near` hit from elasticsearch. Ultimately, I would like to extract the phrase along with a couple of tokens to the left and to the right of the span terms. I learnt about highlighters and thought they are the way to go.

Say this is my query:

```
GET morf_texts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_term": {
            "content": {
              "value": "estetyczny"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term": {
            "content": {
              "value": "zachowanie"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 3,
      "in_order": false
    }
  },
  "highlight": {"fields": {"content": {}}}
}
```

The result hits are listed like this:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.672149,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "morf_texts",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.672149,
        "_source": {
          "content": """
Piękno – pozytywna właściwość estetyczna bytu wynikająca z zachowania proporcji, harmonii barw, dźwięków, stosowności, umiaru i użyteczności, odbierana przez zmysły. Istnieje piękno idealne, duchowe, moralne, naturalne, cielesne, obiektywne i subiektywne. Pojęcie to jest silnie związane z teorią estetyki, prawdy i dobra.
W metafizyce, piękno jest jedną z transcendentalnych właściwości bytu, wyrażającą jego scalenie, przejrzystość, proporcję wewnętrzną tworzyw bytu oraz doskonałość.
Badaniami nad precyzowaniem terminu piękna zajmują się nie tylko filozofowie i artyści, lecz także teoretycy z dziedzin: historii i krytyki sztuki, antropologii, socjologii, psychologii, a także szkolnictwa.
"""
        },
        "highlight": {
          "content": [
            "Piękno – pozytywna właściwość <em>estetyczna</em> bytu wynikająca z <em>zachowania</em> proporcji, harmonii barw, dźwięków"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

This is already great because I get three tokens to the left of `estetyczna` and four to the right of `zachowania`. Is there a way to control how many tokens to the left and right it will highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after looking for a solution for some time, I think there's no way to control the number of tokens to the left or right.

What can be controlled, though, is the number of characters each fetched fragment contains. If the number of characters is big enough, then the fragment should hopefully have enough context to the left and to the right to fulfill the token count requirement.

An example of query using `fragment_size` parameter would look like this:

```
GET morf_texts/_search
{
  "query": {
      ...
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```